# Creating an isValid method

Tags: java

I am working on a mini assignment for a Com. Science class, it is a beginner class, but I have no prior coding experience, so I am struggling with even the basics. I will be asking multiple questions, I do apologize. We are being asked to create a method to move through all of the characters of a string to see if they are A G C or T.

```
/**
 *  Determines whether all characters in this strand are valid
 *  ('A', 'G', 'C', or 'T')
 * @return true if all characters are valid, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isValid() {
```

In a lab for the class we are given this:

```
private static int countP(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.length())
    {
        if (isLetterP(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            count += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I know I have to use the above, I came up with this so far:

```
public boolean isValid() {
    int i = 0;  
    while (i < DNA.length()) {
        if (isValid(DNA.charAt(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

I know I have to work on the if (isValid(DNA.charAT(i) ))[ line, but I am lost, I am not really sure what I need to do. If anyone can not give me the answer flat out but help guide me, that would be awesome.

Comment: Your intent is unclear.  You wish to pass in a character to `isValid`?  Note that your `isValid` as written takes no arguments, so that's not going to compile.  Do you want to check `countP` against `DNA` instead?  Where is it even *coming* from?

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing whether `DNA.charAt(i)` is one of AGCT characters? You may do so by testing `DNA.charAt(i) == 'A'`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isValid (String s) {
    if (s == null) return false;
    char[] ch = s.toLower().toCharArray();
    for (char c : ch) if (c != 'a' && c != 'c' && c != 'g' && c != 't') return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to check if your input string matches a certain pattern - in this case the string should contain only four characters (A, G, C and T) and I am assuming their lower case also -

```
public static boolean isValid (String str) {
    if (str == null) return false;
        // In case lowercase letters are not required you can remove them from the pattern below 
    if (str.matches("^[aAgGcCtT]*$")) return true;
    return false;
}
```